# Unity why does my object rotate exactly the same around the y axis in both Space.Self and Space.World?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinate-transformation

So I was told that Space.Self rotates around local coordinates and Space.World around global coordinates. So I created a small little project and script in unity to verify. However, they both seem to rotating the same way. Is there something I'm doing wrong?[image: My simple setup for testing]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spin : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isSpinOnSelf = true;

    public bool isSpinOnWorld = false;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(isSpinOnSelf)
            transform.Rotate(0,3f,0, Space.Self);

        if(isSpinOnWorld)
            transform.Rotate(0, 3f, 0, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick tip for when you're moving forward: you don't need two bools here. This has the potential to introduce bugs in the future. You can just use if (isSpinOnself) do spinning on self, else, do spin on world stuff.

Comment: @Adam B Goof catch! I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the object's Y axis is still aligned with the world's Y axis.

You're spinning around the same axis. If you rotated the object so that its Y axis was horizontal, you would notice a difference between the two. In local space the object would appear to "roll" whereas in world space it would still rotate "sideways".